# Q. I wanted to know that how we can change the mode of dynamodb multiple tables using AWS-CLI

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface

I need to change the capacity mode of multiple dynamodb tables and I want to do that by using a script written in bash or python. As I'm new to this so I'm looking for some help from experts in this field.

I tried to build a script my self but I have many doubts in that so looking for clear answers here.

Comment: Could you share the code/script that you tried ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.